# What is the Provider Authority String in ProviderTestCase2 constructor?

Tags: android

Can you please tell me what is Provider Authority String in ProviderTestCase2 constructor?

From the JavaDoc below
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ProviderTestCase2.html

it requires 'Provider Authority String', my question I am using it to unit test my Content Provider, so what is my Provider Authority String?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you application's `AndroidManifest.xml` you declare your provider in a next way:

```
<provider android:name=".provider.MyProvider" 
          android:authorities="com.company.app.provider"/>
```

In your `ProviderTestCase2` class you should then specify `com.company.app.provider` as second parameter to super constructor.

For example:

```
public class MyProviderTest extends ProviderTestCase2<MyProvider>
{
    public MyProviderTest()
    {
        super(MyProvider.class, "com.company.app.provider");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should write the code:

```
 public void setup () {
                mContactProvider = mProviderClass.newInstance();
        Context context = getContext();
        mContactProvider.attachInfo(context, null);
        mMockContentResolver.addProvider(authority, mContactProvider);

}
```

then you can operate your contentprovider data